# How to properly Queue animations/transitions using the jQuery Cycle Plugin

Tags: jquery, html

I'm working on this [project](http://parker.astonishlive.com/)

I want to queue my animations in the fader/slider.

```
<script>
$(function() {
  // Hover Switch
   function fnFadeHover(){$('#feature_fadeSlideshow').cycle($('#feature_fadeBtns li').index($(this).parent()));}
   function fnFadeOut(){}
   $('#feature_fadeSlideshow').cycle({
     //fx:'fade',
     timeout:9000,
     delay:5000,
     pause:true,
     after:onAfter,
     before: function(currSlideElement, nextSlideElement, options, afterCallBack, forwardFlag){
       console.log('before');
       var slide_index = $('#feature_fadeSlideshow .panel').index(nextSlideElement);
       $('#feature_fadeBtns li').removeClass('activePager').eq(slide_index).addClass('activePager');    

        $('#auto-automobile').animate({"top": "75px","left": "-2000px"}, "slow",  function(){
           $('#auto-sun').animate({"top": "-300px"}, "slow", function(){
             $('#auto-cloud').animate({"top": "20px", "right":"300px"}, "slow", function(){
               $('#auto-smallCloud').animate({"top": "10px"}, "slow")})

         $('#home-house').animate({"top": "-300px", "left": "310px"}, "slow", function(){
           $('#home-tree').animate({"bottom":"-400px"}, "slow", function(){
             $('#home-smallCloud').animate({"top": "20px"}, "slow")})
           }); 

          $('#business-highway').animate({"top": "-200px"}, "slow", function(){
           $('#business-buildings').animate({"bottom": "-400px"}, "slow", function(){
             $('#business-cloud').animate({"top": "20px"}, "slow")})
           });       

          $('#life-object').animate({"top": "150px"}, "slow", function(){
           $('#life-flowers').animate({"top": "131px"}, "slow", function(){
             $('#life-scope').animate({"top": "284px"}, "slow")})
           });

          });
         });       
     }});
   $('#feature_fadeBtns li a').hoverIntent(fnFadeHover,300,fnFadeOut);
});  
      function onAfter() { 
           $('#auto-automobile').animate({"top": "75px","left": "260px"}, "slow", function(){
               $('#auto-sun').animate({"top": "0px", "right":"400px"}, "slow", function(){
                 $('#auto-cloud').animate({"top": "20px"}, "slow", function(){
                   $('#auto-smallCloud').animate({"top": "20px", "left": "415px"}, "slow")})

         $('#home-house').animate({"top": "105px", "left": "310px"}, "slow", function(){
           $('#home-tree').animate({"top": "90px"}, "slow", function(){
             $('#home-smallCloud').animate({"top": "25px", "right":"5px"}, "slow")})
           }); 

          $('#business-highway').animate({"top": "200px"}, "slow", function(){
           $('#business-buildings').animate({"bottom": "60px"}, "slow", function(){
             $('#business-cloud').animate({"top": "30px"}, "slow")})
           });   


          $('#life-object').animate({"top": "150px"}, "slow", function(){
           $('#life-flowers').animate({"top": "131px"}, "slow", function(){
             $('#life-scope').animate({"top": "284px"}, "slow")})
           });
        });
      }); 
}
</script>
[[Content]]
```

​

**Goal**
If you hover over the navigation under the fader/slider you will see that my animations are not working properly. They Jump around. I want the animation to animate when i hover over auto/home/business or life or when they transition.

As of right now it isn't working properly. **Any suggestions?**

Comment: It looks like it's working, just not the way you wanted it to? What's the issue

Comment: when you hover over home it displays the house. what is suppose to happen is when i hover over home, the house comes down and the tree goes up. But because all my animations are happening once the DOM loads it isn't working the way i want it to. same thing with business. Life isn't set up yet. @mcpDESIGNS

Comment: I think in situations like this, these items should be hidden to begin with, then they animate into the correct position. And when you go to some other animation, make sure that previous one goes back to its hidden positions. If i'm understanding you right..

Comment: so are you suggesting i use `display:none` ? @mcpDESIGNS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to do something like this:

[**jsFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/6dUft/4/)

What I was trying to convey in comments is that you want your positions to *start* as hidden (whatever top/bottom px amount it takes to do that). THEN, you animate then into the correct position.

Super basic example, but you get the idea here. They originally started off as hidden from view, then they both appear one at a time.

```
#one { position:absolute; top:-500px; }
#two { position:absolute; bottom:-500px; }​

$('#one').animate({ left: '50px', top: '0px' }, 'slow', function () {
    $('#two').animate({ left: '200px', bottom: '200px' }, 'slow');
});​
```

Comment: yes this is what i'm trying to do but i think because i am using the cycle plugin it isn't working properly. if you visit http://parker.astonishlive.com/ you will see that if you hover over home you will see what i am talking about. the house appears then hides then appears again.

Comment: is there a way i can queue this? i am using the `before` and `after` properties from the `cycle plugin`

Comment: I don't think that is the issue so much as in the position of the house originally. Seems like it starts out right there in the center. Can you verify that?

Comment: i double checked and it doesn't start out in the center. i checked my styles and even firebugged the house and removed the `positioning` that the `js` adds and it does start off at `-500px` as how i want it too. The styles are being added through the plugin.

Comment: how can i make the animations `animate` once?